# cast from Object to Class : failed

Tags: java, hql

I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to xxx.xxx.xxx.Terminal

when i try this code; so what is wrong ??

```
for(int k=0;k<argTerminal.length;k++){         
String hql = "select crimpkontakt from Terminal where id="+argTerminal[k];
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
 query.setMaxResults(1);
 Terminal nameTerminal = (Terminal) query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Looks like `uniqueResult` returns an `Object[]`, and an `Object[]` is not a `Terminal`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to select Terminal object your HQL should look like:

```
String hql = "from Terminal where id="+argTerminal[k]
```

Also in order to avoid SQL injection using parameters API is a preferred option:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select from Terminal where id = :id");
query.setString("id", argTerminal[k]); // I assume that id is a String here
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

Even better if `id` is a primary key you can use `session.get(Terminal.class, argTerminal[k])`